# Searching for a word in a file

Tags: search, erlang

I'm new to erlang, and I want to lern it. I want to implement a simple word search from a file, it only should display the word, if it is in the file.

I starts like this:

```
readlines(FileName, Word) ->
 {ok, File} = file:open(FileName ,[read]),
    try get_all_lines(File, Word)
      after file:close(File)
    end.

 get_all_lines(File, Word) ->
  io:get_line(File, "") of eof  -> [];
  if word = searchWord -> display(word);
  true -> io:fwrite("no such word in file")
  end.
```

Am I approaching it correctly, or should I try another approach? Or is there somewhere a simply implementation of this? Could someone help me with this?

P.S. Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if it's good enough but you may try to read file then split it in words

and check whether lists contains the word you passing through

```
readlines(FileName, Word) ->
    {ok, Data} = file:read_file(FileName),
    ListOfWords = binary:split(Data, [<<"\n">>, <<" ">>], [global, trim_all]),

    case lists:member(Word, ListOfWords) of
        true -> Word;
        false -> undefined
    end.

1> c(test).                                                                            
{ok,test} 
2> test:readlines("/home/tmp/some.txt", <<"Bin">>). 
undefined
3> test:readlines("/home/tmp/some.txt",<<"This">>).
<<"This">>
```